# Toggle button fails to function

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var mylogin = document.getElementById('login'); //form id for login page
var myRegister = document.getElementById('register'); //form id for register page
var mybtn = document.getElementById('btn'); //btn id to perform toggle option


login = () => {
  mylogin.style.left = '50px';
  myRegister.style.left = '500px';
  mybtn.style.left = '0px';
}

register = () => {
  mylogin.style.left = '-450px';
  myRegister.style.left = '50px';
  mybtn.style.left = '110px';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/*to set background container*/

.container {
  height: 115%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('../Images/conifers.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
}


/*to create white box*/

.form_container {
  width: 380px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 6% auto;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Container to create button on for the shadow effect*/

.button_group {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 34px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 30px;
}


/*Button Styling*/

.toggle_btn {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*style for buttons to toggle*/

#btn {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, lightgreen, green);
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: .5s;
}


/*icons background container*/

.media_icons {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/*icons image style*/

.media_icons img {
  width: 35px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px olivedrab;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*To style form*/

.form_group {
  top: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  transition: .5s;
}


/*for input type=text that is textbox*/

.input_area {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
}

.check_box {
  margin: 30px 10px 30px 0;
}

span {
  color: rgb(36, 21, 22);
  font-size: 14px;
  bottom: 65px;
}

.sub_btn {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, lightgreen, green);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

#login {
  left: 50px;
}

#register {
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form_container">
    <div class="button_group">
      <div id="btn"></div>
      <button type="button" class="toggle_btn" onclick="login()">LOGIN</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle_btn" onclick="register()">REGISTER</button>
    </div>
    <div class="media_icons">
      <img src="~/Images/facebook.png" />
      <img src="~/Images/twitter.png" />
      <img src="~/Images/youtube.jpg" />
      <img src="~/Images/instagram.png" />
    </div>
    <form id="login" class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="UserName" required/>
      <input type="password" class="input_area" placeholder="Password" required />
      <input type="checkbox" class="check_box" /><span>Remenber Me</span>
      <button type="submit" class="sub_btn">LOGIN</button>
    </form>
    <form id="register" class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="UserName" required />
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="Enter Email" required />
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="Enter Password" required />
      <input type="checkbox" class="check_box" />
      <span>I agree with all the terms and conditions </span>
      <button type="submit" class="sub_btn">REGISTER</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not able to find error.Toggle button does not work well.Login and Registration page appears one below the other.Please help me find the mistake.Toggle should work as login button to display login page and register button to display registration form.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the following code

```
#login {
  left: 50px;
}

#register {
  left: 500px;
}
```

with this

```
#login {
    left: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

 #register {
   left: 500px;
   top: 150px;
   position: absolute;
 }
```

I gave `#login` `position: relative;` so it maintains the container height but now you can use `left`

I gave `#register` `position: absulute;` so you can place it where `#login` used to be on toggle

```js
var mylogin = document.getElementById('login'); //form id for login page
var myRegister = document.getElementById('register'); //form id for register page
var mybtn = document.getElementById('btn'); //btn id to perform toggle option


login = () => {
  mylogin.style.left = '50px';
  myRegister.style.left = '500px';
  mybtn.style.left = '0px';
}

register = () => {
  mylogin.style.left = '-450px';
  myRegister.style.left = '50px';
  mybtn.style.left = '110px';
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/*to set background container*/

.container {
  height: 115%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('../Images/conifers.jpg');
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
}


/*to create white box*/

.form_container {
  width: 380px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 6% auto;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/*Container to create button on for the shadow effect*/

.button_group {
  width: 220px;
  margin: 34px auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px darkseagreen;
  border-radius: 30px;
}


/*Button Styling*/

.toggle_btn {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*style for buttons to toggle*/

#btn {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, lightgreen, green);
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: .5s;
}


/*icons background container*/

.media_icons {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/*icons image style*/

.media_icons img {
  width: 35px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px olivedrab;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/*To style form*/

.form_group {
  top: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  transition: .5s;
}


/*for input type=text that is textbox*/

.input_area {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
}

.check_box {
  margin: 30px 10px 30px 0;
}

span {
  color: rgb(36, 21, 22);
  font-size: 14px;
  bottom: 65px;
}

.sub_btn {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, lightgreen, green);
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}

#login {
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#register {
  left: 500px;
  top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="form_container">
    <div class="button_group">
      <div id="btn"></div>
      <button type="button" class="toggle_btn" onclick="login()">LOGIN</button>
      <button type="button" class="toggle_btn" onclick="register()">REGISTER</button>
    </div>
    <div class="media_icons">
      <img src="~/Images/facebook.png" />
      <img src="~/Images/twitter.png" />
      <img src="~/Images/youtube.jpg" />
      <img src="~/Images/instagram.png" />
    </div>
    <form id="login" class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="UserName" required />
      <input type="password" class="input_area" placeholder="Password" required />
      <input type="checkbox" class="check_box" /><span>Remenber Me</span>
      <button type="submit" class="sub_btn">LOGIN</button>
    </form>
    <form id="register" class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="UserName" required />
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="Enter Email" required />
      <input type="text" class="input_area" placeholder="Enter Password" required />
      <input type="checkbox" class="check_box" />
      <span>I agree with all the terms and conditions </span>
      <button type="submit" class="sub_btn">REGISTER</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much.

Comment: @saifuddinharianawala if my answer helped to resolve your problem could you accept it as the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

1.First you add display none to id

```
 #register{
  display:none;
}
 #login{
  display:block;
}
```

2. Then in file js you just need change style display when ever onclick.

   ```
   login = () => {
        mylogin.style.left = '50px';
        myRegister.style.left = '500px';
        mybtn.style.left = '0px';
        mylogin.style.display='block'
      myRegister.style.display='none'
    }

    register = () => {
        mylogin.style.left = '-450px';
        myRegister.style.left = '50px';
        mybtn.style.left = '110px';
      myRegister.style.display='block'
      mylogin.style.display='none'

    }
   ```

Comment: Try my codepen https://codepen.io/hoang1510-dt/pen/qBbQPwv